# Объединить сходные теги по Angular для простоты

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Не смог найти способа написать непосредственно кому-то из модераторов, и какого-то отдельного тега для таких вопросов, поэтому рискну написать тут, если что не так - прошу прощения, просто удалите этот вопрос.

Суть.

Не мог бы кто-то у кого достаточно прав объединить существующие теги `angular#` в один тег `angular`, по аналогии с англоязычным stackoverflow. Т.е. чтобы был `angularjs` для первой версии и просто `angular` для 2+, ибо смысла деления на версии старше первой практически нет, тем более что уже и 6я вышла...